# Modify the content of a large string

Tags: android, string, kotlin, recursion

I am receiving some large String content that contains several numbers demarcating sections. 
I'm trying to modify the content in such a way that if a number is present, a line break is inserted. 
So that something like: *"1.This is one line. 2. This is another. 3. Here is one more."*

gets modified to something like this: 
"1.This is one line.
 2. This is another.
 3. Here is one more."
I tried solving it this way:

```kotlin
fun modifyText(inputStr: String):String {
        val marker= listOf('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7')
        var text = ""
       marker.forEach {
           if (inputStr.contains(it)) {
               text = inputStr.replace(it.toString(), "\n $it" )
           }
       }
       return text
}
```

This only modified the section with the last number and not everything.
Thought of using recursion this way:

```kotlin
tailrec fun modifyText(inputStr: String):String {
        val marker= listOf('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7')
        var text = ""
       marker.forEach {
           if (inputStr.contains(it)) {
               text = inputStr.replace(it.toString(), "\n $it" )
           }
       }
       return modifyText(text)
} 
but ended up "bricking" the app.
Please any solutions to how this can be achieved will be appreciated.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second attempt "bricks the app" because you are writing a function with infinite recursion (it calls itself but has no stopping condition). This usually fails with `StackOverflowError`, but with `tailrec` you probably end up with an infinite loop instead - not much better.

There is no need for recursion in your case, `replace()` will take care of all occurrences of your matching string.

Your problem in your first attempt is that `text = inputStr.replace(it.toString(), "\n $it" )` always reuses the initial `inputStr` instead of the modified `text`. So all the replacements you already did are not taken into account, and only the replacement for the last "marker" (7) is effective.
You can change it by using `text` instead of `inputStr`, and initializing `text` to the `inputStr`:

```kotlin
fun modifyText(inputStr: String):String {
    val marker= listOf('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7')
    var text = inputStr
    marker.forEach {
        if (inputStr.contains(it)) {
            text = text.replace(it.toString(), "\n $it" )
        }
    }
    return text
}
```

Note that for this you can also directly use a regular expression, without listing all numbers manually. It may be more efficient, and more importantly it is much simpler:

```kotlin
val modifiedStr = inputStr.replace(Regex("""\d"""), "\n $0")
```

If you're not familiar with regexes, here is what happens:

- `\d` matches a single digit
- `$0` in the replacement string represents the value of the matching group 0, which is the entire match (so, the digit that was matched by the regex). If there were parenthese in the regex, each pair of parentheses defines a new group (numbered 1, 2, 3, etc).

You can also improve on this regex if you want to match digits followed by `.` (in your input it looks like it's always followed by `.`, so it would avoid matching numbers that are not section numbers):

```kotlin
val modifiedStr = inputStr.replace(Regex("""\d\."""), "\n $0")
```

A last improvement, if you have section numbers with more than 1 digit, you can use the `+` modifier to indicate "one or more":

```kotlin
val modifiedStr = inputStr.replace(Regex("""\d+\."""), "\n $0")
```

Comment: This is tidier than the regex solution I was experimenting with. It could also match against "\d+\." if the period is required.

Comment: @PPartisan I was literally editing to add this :)

Answer (score 1):

you can just replace every "marker" character in the string with the marker + a newline.
No need for recursion.
Something like this

```
val marker= listOf('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7')
var text = inputStr
marker.forEach {
   text = text.replace(it.toString(), "\n$it" )
}
return text
```

Comment: Won't you have a new line at the very beginning since '1' is present in the list?

Answer (score 1):

Your all logic is good , but you are missing something . you have to update the old string with the update value.

```
      fun main() {
                var inputStr = "1. This is one line. 2. This is another. 3. 
                 Here is one more."
                 val marker= listOf('1', '2', '3', '4', 
                 '5', '6', '7')
                   var text = ""
                  marker.forEach {
                    if (inputStr.contains(it)) {
              text = inputStr.replace(it.toString(), "\n $it" )
            **// so only add this , and it will work fine :)**
             inputStr=text
         }
              println(text)
     }
    
}
```